# CSOM Caml Query Not able to find file - SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

I am try to get the following file "GC_SELF_TEST.ppt" document from the following folder

[image: Folder]

When I run my code, it does not return any results.
I'm quiet certain the problem is in my CamlQuery (I'm new to CSOM and CamlQuery).

I would just like to get this document for download purposes. Any help would Appreciated!

```
        String site = "http://SPsite/";
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(site);
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Password", "Domain");

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                            <Where>
                                <Eq> 
                                   <FieldRef Name='Name'/>
                                   <Value Type='Text'>GC_SELF_TEST</Value>
                                </Eq>
                            </Where>
                         </View>";

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents").GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(docs);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem doc in docs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(doc.Id);
        }
```

I also tried the following Query but no results:

`"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>GC_SELF_TEST.pptx</Value></Eq></Where></View>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal name of the Name field is actually `FileLeafRef` so your `FieldRef` tag should look like this: `<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>`

I believe you'll also want to include the file extension in the value of your query.

Comment: ? I can't see you example. I only see: '

Comment: I tried the following query: "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>GC_SELF_TEST.pptx</Value></Eq></Where></View>" But no results